# Code Igniter SQL Query: how to create this query

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

This is the first time I will be using a MVC and i have read the documentation of code igniter.. but i cant seem to get this query right:

```
$score = $_POST['time'];
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(score) as c FROM highscores WHERE score < '$score' ORDER BY score ASC LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$count = mysqli_fetch_object($result)->c;
if(!is_null($count) && $count < 10) {
    echo 1;
}
```

and then my code igniter version:

```
public function insert_highscore($score) {
    $this->db->select('COUNT(score) as c')->from('highscores')->where('score < ' . $score);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $count = $query->c;
    if(!is_null($count) && $count < 10) {
        echo 1;
    }
    return $count;
}
```

and i call that function like so:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->model('highscores_model');
    $data = $this->highscores_model->get_highscores();
    $this->highscores_model->insert_highscore("00:00:01.11");
    foreach($data as $highscore){
        echo $highscore['name'];
        echo $highscore['score'];
    }
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

and getting this error

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':00:01.11' at line 3

SELECT COUNT(score) as c FROM (`highscores`) WHERE `score` < 00:00:01.11

Filename: /storage/websites/cambist_app/codeigniter/models/highscores_model.php

Line Number: 15
```

Any Help Greatly Appreciated

Comment: What's not working? Getting undesired result from query or is query/function failing to return anything?

Comment: hi just change your where method where('score < ' , $score) don't concat your string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your model method you are just running query but not fetching records just after your db->get() put row() or result method to get records against query row will get only single record result will get object of records as array also in you where i made little modification

```
public function insert_highscore($score) {
    $this->db->select('COUNT(score) as c')->from('highscores')->where('score < ' , $score);
    $query = $this->db->get()->row();
    $count = $query->c;
    if(!is_null($count) && $count < 10) {
        echo 1;
    }
    return $count;
}
```

you can use the count_all_results to get all records

```
 public function insert_highscore($score) {
        $this->db->where('score < ' , $score);
        $count = $this->db->count_all_results('highscores');
        if(!is_null($count) && $count < 10) {
            echo 1;
        }
        return $count;
    }
```

Comment: Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':00:01.11' at line 3

SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows` FROM (`highscores`) WHERE `score` < 00:00:01.11

Filename: /storage/websites/cambist_app/codeigniter/models/highscores_model.php

Line Number: 15

Comment: hi just change your where method where('score < ' , $score) don't concat your string if you score column data type is varchar then you need to use score "00:00:01:11"

Comment: hey, seems to have done something.. thank you.. just have :  '$score' in 'where clause' that now